Air Compressor leak
Hi I have a s g s  air compressor
After use the tank shows pressure at7.5 Bar but slowly empties
Should this happen??
I’ve used leak detector spray for leaks but non showing after spraying
Has anyone any clues ??

How slowly? All things leak; if it leaks slowly enough not to be a problem, it's not a problem.

Have you tried resetting all the fittings?

Any compressor I have had leaks slowly.  If you are talking about  a loss overnight or longer it is normal.   How much of a loss, you have not indicated, so I can't comment further.

It's possible to have a leak free air compressor. It's not common, though. Since you should drain the tank to remove water (which comes from humidity in the air) out to prevent tank corrosion, often easiest just to normalize shutting down & draining the tank between uses. Otherwise  it's down to isolating the leak and fixing it. It may be easier to fill a portable air tank that doesn't leak (slightly more common) for small jobs without starting the compressor.

With the leak detector fluid, check around the regulator. But as noted, these things don’t hold pressure forever…
